# rpm -Uvh & yum install

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql, yum, rpm

I am new to linux and wants to understand the reason for using some commands. I am trying to install PostgreSQL on CentOs by following the instructions [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation).

First we do `rpm -ivh pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpm` which installs the rpm package into the system. But why does it ask us to do `yum install postgresql91-server` (which i assume installs postgresql) again if we have used `rpm -ivh` to install the package?

Additionally, what is the reason for adding the lines `exclude=postgresql*` into `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` under `[base]` and `[updates]`. Why is it that we exclude yum from accessing these packages, then use yum to install `postgresql91-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum` interfaces with the online repository related to your version of CentOS.

`rpm` is the package manager and packaging format for applications developed for the Red Hat/CentOS platform. Your `rpm` command is installing a packaged that was downloaded and is not part of a yum repository.

In the Windows world, it's like the difference between Windows Update (yum) and downloading a piece of software and double-clicking an installer (rpm).

It also appears as though you're using a version of postgresql that is newer than the one available through the normal CentOS channels ("Base" and "Updates"). The package being installed by the yum command you listed is coming from a different [third-party software repository](http://yum.pgrpms.org/repopackages.php).

It looks like you're using the postgres database packages provided directly be PostgreSQL instead of the ones that come via CentOS. The [instructions and reasoning are detailled here](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_postgresql_9_on_centos).

As a result, you've been asked to prevent the version that's is distributed with CentOS from installing by using the `exclude=` statements you listed. This is a precautionary measure to avoid a conflict between the older version of postgresql from CentOS and the newer one you're installing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why insert the  `exclude=postgresql*` then do a `yum install postgresql91-server`? Also, doesnt `rpm -ivh` already perform the installation, why continue with a `yum install`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx The `pgdg-centos91*` file contains the information that tells your system where to look in order to actually download the PostgreSQL packages via `yum`. So you have to install that part manually using `rpm`. See my edited answer above.